# C++ Does this code modify any data pointer to this or does it just return it?

Tags: c++

It seems that everytime I call this function. Like so, it actually works right.. But I want to avoid calling functions because this can sometimes crash if parameters are wrong, so I want to rely on just modifying memory addresses/values to avoid that issue.

Here is the working hook CALL.

```
DWORD thisPointer = 0xABCDEF;
typedef int(__thiscall* dwordHookFunction )(DWORD a1, DWORD a2);
dwordHookFunction testCall;
testCall = (dwordHookFunction)0x5E0280; //Address matches ForceSlectionFunction offset.

testCall(thisPointer, 1);
```

Here is the function decompiled.

```
int __thiscall ForceSelectionFunction(int this, int a2)
{
  int result; // eax

  if ( a2 > 0 && a2 < *(_DWORD *)(this + 4) )
    result = *(_DWORD *)this + 0x1E9B8 * a2;
  else
    result = 0;
  return result;
}
```

How does this function modify the memory for `this` pointer does it even modify it? Does it even modify anything or just return data?.. It has to modify something because otherwise it wouldn't work I think..

How would I go about calling the changes?

```
*(unsigned int*)(0xABCDEF + 0x1E9B8 * 1) = ???
```

or is it

```
*(unsigned int*)(0xABCDEF) = 0x1E9B8 * 1 //???
```

P.S.> anyone want to look at the ASM code here it is.

```
seg000:005E0280 ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
seg000:005E0280
seg000:005E0280 ; Attributes: bp-based frame
seg000:005E0280
seg000:005E0280 ; int __thiscall ForceSelectionFunction(_DWORD this, int a2)
seg000:005E0280 ForceSelectionFunction proc near    ; CODE XREF: sub_412260+618↑p
seg000:005E0280                                         ; sub_415240+F6↑p ...
seg000:005E0280
seg000:005E0280 var_4           = dword ptr -4
seg000:005E0280 a2              = dword ptr  8
seg000:005E0280
seg000:005E0280                 push    ebp
seg000:005E0281                 mov     ebp, esp
seg000:005E0283                 push    ecx
seg000:005E0284                 mov     [ebp+var_4], ecx
seg000:005E0287                 cmp     [ebp+a2], 0
seg000:005E028B                 jle     short loc_5E0298
seg000:005E028D                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_4]
seg000:005E0290                 mov     ecx, [ebp+a2]
seg000:005E0293                 cmp     ecx, [eax+4]
seg000:005E0296                 jl      short loc_5E029C
seg000:005E0298
seg000:005E0298 loc_5E0298:                             ; CODE XREF: ForceSelectionFunction+B↑j
seg000:005E0298                 xor     eax, eax
seg000:005E029A                 jmp     short loc_5E02AA
seg000:005E029C ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
seg000:005E029C
seg000:005E029C loc_5E029C:                             ; CODE XREF: ForceSelectionFunction+16↑j
seg000:005E029C                 mov     eax, [ebp+a2]
seg000:005E029F                 imul    eax, 1E9B8h
seg000:005E02A5                 mov     edx, [ebp+var_4]
seg000:005E02A8                 add     eax, [edx]
seg000:005E02AA
seg000:005E02AA loc_5E02AA:                             ; CODE XREF: ForceSelectionFunction+1A↑j
seg000:005E02AA                 mov     esp, ebp
seg000:005E02AC                 pop     ebp
seg000:005E02AD                 retn    4
seg000:005E02AD ForceSelectionFunction endp
```

In a older version of this game it decompiles like so.. which is pretty much the same thing just with some struct work done.

```
int __thiscall ForceSelectionFunction(_DWORD *this, int a2)
{
  int result; // eax

  if ( a2 <= 0 || a2 >= this[1] )
    result = 0;
  else
    result = *this + 0x1FB50 * a2;
  return result;
}
```

Comment: what does this function do? What are you trying to do? And why?

Comment: It a function that helps in cheating inside a video game, without calling it.. I cannot do automation in the game that well, so its just a essential part I need to finish to get my bot finished

Comment: Your objective is unclear to me, `*(unsigned int*)(0xABCDEF + 0x1E9B8 * 1) = ???` and `*(unsigned int*)(0xABCDEF) = 0x1E9B8 * 1 //???` are different things. The first one will write some `unsigned int` at the address `0xABCDEF + 0x1E9B8 * 1` ( = `0xADB7A7`) and the second one writes `0x1E9B8` at address `0xABCDEF`

Comment: Yes I want to be able to write.. I think that will make the function trigger and do it's function but I cannot figure out how to do the write properly doesn't seem very clear in the decompiled code, I don't even think it writes anything by looking at the pseudo C Code or maybe just some curly brackets are missing but I still cannot find the equals sign so i dont understand it.

Comment: Is `*(_DWORD *)this + 0x1E9B8 * a2;` this somehow evaluated as a write equation to write on `this` using the `+` ? some kind of lvl 2 pointer thats as far I can guess.

Comment: @SSpoke No, that wouldn't write anything anywhere. Instead, that would fetch a `_DWORD` at what address `this` points to and adds `0x1E9B8 * a2` to it and finally returns the value. Moreover, I don't think naming an argument as `this` is viable in C++.

Comment: yes the C++ code is just pesudo code it's not meant to be run without renaming it and fixing it up a bit. Anyways I kinda gave up on this.. going to just stick to just calling the function.. and try to catch/filter all parameters that may crash it. I ran a breakpoint inside this called function and it seems to be called a milion times somewhere so I guess that's where it reads the results and does the actions, still no clue how myself calling it makes it work as I call it from a random area and the result never reaches the caller.. screw it. Maybe the key is `xor     eax, eax` ?